# Confluent connect unble to create sink using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am implementing a Kafka MongoDB connecter to sink data in MongoDB. Using the document I have configured a connecter. But could not able to connect it. I get a log from the connect like this. Where all the components are in docker and my database installed in my local machine.

```
[2021-06-08 12:14:14,232] INFO Cluster created with settings {hosts=[192.168.1.23:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'} (org.mongodb.driver.cluster:71)
[2021-06-08 12:14:14,262] INFO MongoSinkTopicConfig values:
        change.data.capture.handler =
        collection = test
        database = admin
        delete.on.null.values = false
        document.id.strategy = com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.BsonOidStrategy
        document.id.strategy.overwrite.existing = false
        document.id.strategy.partial.key.projection.list =
        document.id.strategy.partial.key.projection.type =
        document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.list =
        document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.type =
        document.id.strategy.uuid.format = string
        errors.log.enable = false
        errors.tolerance = none
        field.renamer.mapping = []
        field.renamer.regexp = []
        key.projection.list =
        key.projection.type = none
        max.batch.size = 0
        max.num.retries = 1
        namespace.mapper = com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.namespace.mapping.DefaultNamespaceMapper
        namespace.mapper.error.if.invalid = false
        namespace.mapper.key.collection.field =
        namespace.mapper.key.database.field =
        namespace.mapper.value.collection.field =
        namespace.mapper.value.database.field =
        post.processor.chain = [com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.DocumentIdAdder]
        rate.limiting.every.n = 0
        rate.limiting.timeout = 0
        retries.defer.timeout = 5000
        topic = test
        value.projection.list =
        value.projection.type = none
        writemodel.strategy = com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.ReplaceOneDefaultStrategy
 (com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.MongoSinkTopicConfig:361)
[2021-06-08 12:14:14,265] INFO MongoSinkTopicConfig values:
        change.data.capture.handler =
        collection = test
        database = admin
        delete.on.null.values = false
        document.id.strategy = com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.BsonOidStrategy
        document.id.strategy.overwrite.existing = false
        document.id.strategy.partial.key.projection.list =
        document.id.strategy.partial.key.projection.type =
        document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.list =
        document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.type =
        document.id.strategy.uuid.format = string
        errors.log.enable = false
        errors.tolerance = none
        field.renamer.mapping = []
        field.renamer.regexp = []
        key.projection.list =
        key.projection.type = none
        max.batch.size = 0
        max.num.retries = 1
        namespace.mapper = com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.namespace.mapping.DefaultNamespaceMapper
        namespace.mapper.error.if.invalid = false
        namespace.mapper.key.collection.field =
        namespace.mapper.key.database.field =
        namespace.mapper.value.collection.field =
        namespace.mapper.value.database.field =
        post.processor.chain = [com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.DocumentIdAdder]
        rate.limiting.every.n = 0
        rate.limiting.timeout = 0
        retries.defer.timeout = 5000
        topic = test
        value.projection.list =
        value.projection.type = none
        writemodel.strategy = com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.ReplaceOneDefaultStrategy
 (com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.MongoSinkTopicConfig:361)
[2021-06-08 12:14:14,275] INFO Cluster created with settings {hosts=[192.168.1.23:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'} (org.mongodb.driver.cluster:71)
[2021-06-08 12:14:16,269] INFO Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 192.168.1.23:27017 (org.mongodb.driver.cluster:76)
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:143)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65)
        ... 4 more
[2021-06-08 12:14:16,316] INFO Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 192.168.1.23:27017 (org.mongodb.driver.cluster:76)
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:143)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65)
        ... 4 more
```

I have a check that from docker image can ping my local IP. I have also verified that my MongoDB up and running.

can anyone help me with this? Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to connect MongoDB using mongo Shell from the container? please share your connector configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs is just because of the different IP i am using to connect my MongoDB. So by default 127.0.0.1 is whitelisted other than that we have to white list. So using the `bindIp` property in the mongo configuration we can achieve this.

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0
```

Note: Here I have whitelist all the ips. You can whitelist as per your need. In a production environment, a wildcard whitelist is not advisable. After changing the property in MongoDB config file restart it.